# Binding a list to multiple comboboxes

Tags: vb.net, binding, combobox

I have bind my list to multiple comboboxes, and everything is working except: when I select a value in one of my comboboxes this is also being selected in all the other comboboxes, while I don't want this.

What I want is an easy way to fill all my 13 comboboxes with the same list, but that you can select a different (or the same) value in all 13.

```
        Dim lstofcolumnheaders As New List(Of String)
        lstofcolumnheaders.Add("")
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            lstofcolumnheaders.Add(dt.Columns(i).ColumnName)
        Next

        cmbArtGroep.DataSource = lstofcolumnheaders
        cmbArtnr.DataSource = lstofcolumnheaders
        cmbArtNrLev.DataSource = lstofcolumnheaders
        cmbBarcode.DataSource = lstofcolumnheaders
        cmbEigenschappen.DataSource = lstofcolumnheaders
        cmbInfo.DataSource = lstofcolumnheaders
        cmbLeverancier.DataSource = lstofcolumnheaders
        cmbMerk.DataSource = lstofcolumnheaders
        cmbMinStock.DataSource = lstofcolumnheaders
        cmbMOQ.DataSource = lstofcolumnheaders
        cmbOmschrijving.DataSource = lstofcolumnheaders
        cmbTotStock.DataSource = lstofcolumnheaders
        cmbType.DataSource = lstofcolumnheaders
```

[image]

My current workaround is:

```
        For Each itm As String In lstofcolumnheaders
            cmbArtGroep.Items.Add(itm)
        Next
```

But I still want to use binding.  Any idea?

Comment: use `cmbArtGroep.DataSource = lstofcolumnheaders.ToArray()` on each of them and they will act independantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plutonix's idea implies that you actual bind to a different list (the problem with your binding is that all combos bind to the same reference and one selection is pushed to all lists).

To go a little further, I would to the following:

1) create a list of `ComboBox`es and push all your controls there

2) for each combo in the list, have its DataSource = lstofcolumnheaders.ToArray()